# How to convert a JSON with array elements to a Java Object on Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I want to convert a JSON than contains an Array element like this:

```
 [{ "_id" : "01001", "city" : "AGAWAM", "loc" : [ -72.622739, 42.070206 ], "pop" : 15338, "state" : "MA" }
,
{ "_id" : "01002", "city" : "CUSHMAN", "loc" : [ -72.51564999999999, 42.377017 ], "pop" : 36963, "state" : "MA" }
,
{ "_id" : "01005", "city" : "BARRE", "loc" : [ -72.10835400000001, 42.409698 ], "pop" : 4546, "state" : "MA" }]
```

The element loc is an array with two elements inside. 
I have the following code to convert the JSON to an Java Object:

```
public ModelAndView listCities() throws IOException {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(ViewConstant.CITIES);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Cities[] obj = mapper.readValue(new File("routeOfTheJSONFile"), Cities[].class);
    mav.addObject("cities", obj);
    return mav;
}
```

My entity looks like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Cities {
    private String _id;
    private String city;
    private double[] loc;
    private String pop;
    private String state;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public double[] getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(double[] loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public String getPop() {
        return pop;
    }

    public void setPop(String pop) {
        this.pop = pop;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cities{" +
                "_id='" + _id + '\'' +
                ", city='" + city + '\'' +
                ", loc=" + Arrays.toString(loc) +
                ", pop='" + pop + '\'' +
                ", state='" + state + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And the HTML like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Starbucks</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Population</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="city : ${cities}">
                    <td th:text="${city._id}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${city.city}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${city.loc}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${city.pop}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${city.state}"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I display the information in a table the loc column comes like this:

```
[D@6481f9f9
[D@41e9a11f
[D@af30d01
```

[It comes in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh9Jm.png)

How can I solve this?

Comment: It's not coming "encrypted", it's coming as the result of Arrays#toString. Try invoking toString on every element of the loc array.

Comment: Whups, you're already using `Arrays.toString()` in your `toString()`, now I'm just confused...  Are you sure that your `toString()` method is actually being used to display the table?

Comment: It depends what are you doing with that `ModelAndView` instance. Do you generate table on server side and send part of `HTML` page back to client? Or you want to return `JSON` via `REST` `API` and handle response on client side?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel dawg, use Jackson or GSON.

Comment: @MichałZiober I want to do a REST API when I send the JSON from the server to the client

Comment: If you're using spring-boot Jackson should already be there

Comment: @RobOhRob I'm using Jackson

Comment: @PaulMiranda, it looks like you use [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#introducing-thymeleaf). Does it true? If you want to create a `REST` method you need to create `Controller` with `GET` method and call it using `Ajax` on client side. But right now you generate page on server side and you do not need it.

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes I'm using Thymeleaf. I have a Controller, is where I convert the JSON file to a Java Object and send it to the View

Comment: @PaulMiranda, have you checked my answer? Right now I am confused. In question you mentioned that there is a problem with `Location` column. Right now you want to change it to `Ajax` call?

Comment: @MichałZiober Yes the problem is whit the Location column who has the col atributte, but I don't want it to change it to Ajax, I just want it to show correctly in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add extra getter to `Cities` class:

```
String getLocation() {
    return loc[0] + " " + loc[1];
}
```

And in script use:

```
<td th:text="${city.location}"></td>
```

Or, if you do not want to create any special getters just iterate over `loc` table like you did for `cities`

**EDIT**
You can always use `${#strings.arrayJoin(city.loc, ' ')}` method.

See:

- [Working With Arrays in Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-arrays)
- [Strings doc](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#strings)

Comment: I tried iterating the loc element like you said but it didn't work, i tried something like this:
. I have checked your answer and I tried to iterate the loc column like you said but it doesn´t worked. I did something like this:
public class citiesLoc {
    private String[] loc;

    public String[] getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String[] loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "citiesLoc{" +
                "loc=" + Arrays.toString(loc) +
                '}';
    }
}

Comment: @PaulMiranda, you do not need to create `citiesLoc` class. Just add one extra getter to `Cities` class

Comment: It worked! But it have to change the type of variable in the Cities class, insted of double I have to change it to String.

Comment: @PaulMiranda, that's strange a little bit. I'm glad I could help. One comment only is to add more info next time to question. Things like template engine are really important. Also, please take a look on this article: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks for the help :) And for the information too!